# Apache - random request lag (linux vps server)

Tags: apache-2.4

On my client server, I am using Laravel 7 with PHP 7.4. For some unknown reason, the server randomly respond slower.

The server is a typical VPS - CentOS Linux 7 (Core); 8x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz; ssd.
Currently RAM usage is low: around 2,7 up to 3,5GB; `HTOP` shows low load between `0.3` to `1.0`.

I've wrote a script to show the problem. Script is calling AJAX 100 times. AJAX is hitting the Laravel app and responds back to script. There is no DB involved in script execution. Here is result:

[image]

At least 95% of the requests are responding without any problems - request time is normal. Only few red ones in screen are lagged. Normal request is taking max 150-300ms;  lagged ones took at least 5s to execute. Every script call is the same. Lag is completely random.

I've reported this problem to server admin but they have no idea what's happening.

Is there any server reason behind that problem?

Comment: Do you have any Apache logs (error.log)? It seems to be an app problem, but I'm not really sure.